# ERROR: Duplicate Record Button

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm, jscript

I am Building a test solution, to test I aim to create a duplicate template of an Account on click of button, plugin then fires to include the copy of all the contacts related.

I am currently doing something Similar to [this post](http://garethtuckercrm.com/tag/openentityform/)

However: Here is the bit of code...

```
function CopyAccount() {
   //Collect values from the existing CRM form that you want to default onto your new record    
   var GUIDvalue = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
   var Namevalue = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("name").getValue();

   if (GUIDvalue != null && Namevalue != null) 
   {
      var parameters = {};
      parameters["new_templateid"] = GUIDvalue;
      parameters["name"] = Namevalue;
      Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm("account", null, parameters);
   }
```

I Get an Error: `SCRIPT5022: id must not be null.`

Comes from global.ashx?ver=-1477464416, line 6 character 372572

```
Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm=function(name,id,parameters){
     if(IsNull(name)) trow Error.create("name must not be null.");
     if(IsNull(id)) throw Error.create("id must not be null.");
     if(IsNull(parameters)) throw Error.create("parameters must not be null.")
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Hi, I don't know if i'm looking well but you pass null to id and because that is throw a exception. But in this function if you pass null means that you want a new record, so i don't understand. Try debug your javascript and verify if GUIDvalue has any value.

Comment: Thanks Pedro, Turns out its microsoft playing around again. http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/crm/thread/33b7b18a-195e-4d7d-9c19-a6ad4e16a672. Found this answer on another forum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this topic on another forum  http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/crm/thread/33b7b18a-195e-4d7d-9c19-a6ad4e16a672